# how to make a box overflow a row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I was wondering how to make this using only Bootstrap ((I'm not sure if I can add an image here, so, this is the image to represent how I need them....))

http://i.imgur.com/pZlR63X.png

I kinda have a code already, which follows

```css
       body {
         padding-top: 50px;
         padding-bottom: 50px;
         margin: 0;
       }
       .text {
         background-color: silver;
         margin-top: 50px;
         margin-left: 30px;
         height: 70px;
       }
       .img-right {
         height: 150px;
         float: right;
         padding-top: -30px;
         overflow: auto;
       }
       .img-left {
         height: 150px;
         float: left;
         padding-top: -30px;
         overflow: auto;
       }
       .box {
         width: 45%;
         display: inline-flex;
       }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container pull-left" style="overflow: auto">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" class="img-left">

      <div class="container-fluid box">
        <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container" style="overflow: auto">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" class="img-right">

      <div class="container-fluid box">
        <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

But, as you all can see, is not even close from what I want.... someone kindly could help me here? I'm not completely sure if its easy to notice, but there's a small space between each "block"... yes, it's intended to be in this way... it will be 2 containers inside a row inside a container.

The left one is almost what I want, but the right one is not even far =)

Cheers =)

Comment: woah. too many `.container`s. The flow should be `container` > `row` > `col-xx-x`. I would suggest spending some time learning the bootstrap structure.

Comment: Yeah... i know about that... but, i think must be in that way.... because it will be 6 different pieces that will get some animation later... for each side it will be the text + row + image.... I couldn't see how this could be in another way.... i will still try some ways here and will show you later on... cheers =)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet to get you started:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <p class="img-text">Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6  text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <p class="img-text">Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With only this CSS:

```
.img-text{
    padding:65px 0;
}
```

[**See it in action here**](http://www.bootply.com/8Xqb25KMoI)

HTH,

-Ted

Comment: Hey @Ted..... actually what I want is like its in the image.... a box really overlaps the row.... think like your mobile above a ruler.... an image will be on the box over the row and will have a small text besides of it....